# Swift iOS: UIButton.frame gives all 0s

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am new to iOS and Swift and the UIKit so there are many items that have proven confusing. I create a UIButton, add some text, and then TRY to get the button's CGRect, but all the values are zero. I am actually just interested in the width.

Here is my code (menuButtonMaxWidth is a class var)

```
    menuButtonMaxWidth = 0
    let overflowItem1 = UIButton()
    let checkboxCharacter: Character = "\u{25EF}"
    overflowItem1.setTitle("\(checkboxCharacter) Allow Hub Wifi Reset", for: [])
    overflowItem1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: [])
    overflowItem1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(overflowItem1Clicked(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    overflowItem1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if overflowItem1.frame.width > menuButtonMaxWidth {
        menuButtonMaxWidth = overflowItem1.frame.width
    }
```

The **overflowItem1.frame.width** always gives zero! Debugging shows that the CGRect of overflowItem1.frame has all zero values. What am I doing wrong? This seems like it should be so straight forward. Thanks for any help. I must be missing something or doing something that is an iOS no-no but have not caught on yet.

I am using Xcode 12 and I assume the latest version of Swift.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? You might be calling it before the UI is actually laid out - hence the 0 frame.

Comment: I call it when I want to create a menu. I tap a menu button, create a series of buttons, create a container, and add the buttons to the container. I am trying to use the btoon size to size my container. If I fix the size of the container, the button displays correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `sizeToFit()` on your button to resize it for its content.

```
    let overflowItem1 = UIButton()
    let checkboxCharacter: Character = "\u{25EF}"
    overflowItem1.setTitle("\(checkboxCharacter) Allow Hub Wifi Reset", for: [])
    overflowItem1.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: [])
            
    overflowItem1.sizeToFit()
    print(overflowItem1.frame.width)
```

Comment: That did the trick. Not sure I understand why that is necessary. Is it because the size of the button defaults to 0 until constraints are put on it?

Comment: Yes, as you don't have any constraints set on the button, it's size is determined by the intrinsic content size (size of title text). But we have to force it to update the frame since it is not added as a subview to any view.